# How to properly configure a Rails mountable engine to work with `twitter-bootswatch-rails` gem?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I am developing a Rails 4.1.13 mountable engine and trying to take advantage if its namespaced features, especially when it comes to the views.

I am trying to dress my engine's views with `Bootstrap`, more specifically using the `twitter-bootswatch-rails` gem.

Among the generators which the gem provides, I have managed to run only one succesfully: `rails g bootswatch:install sunrise` which will generate the respective files, even though they will not really be namespaced under my Engine's name. Changing the filenames in `$engine_name/layouts/application.html.haml` would do the trick.

However, the behavior of ignoring the engine's namespace leads to the rest of the gem's generators to spit an error similar to this:

```
$> rails g bootswatch:themed Datasets
$engine_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/twitter-bootswatch-rails-3.3.4.0/lib/generators/bootswatch/themed/themed_generator.rb:91:in `ext': undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Line 91 of [themed_generator](https://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-bootswatch-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/bootswatch/themed/themed_generator.rb) is trying to find out which template generator the `::Rails.application` is using but it considers this to be `nil`

My `engine.rb` file is as follows:

```
module Meticulous
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    isolate_namespace Meticulous
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, fixtures: false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
      g.assets true
      g.helpers true
    end

    config.app_generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :haml
      g.stylesheet_engine :less
    end

    config.assets.precompile += %w( sunrise.css sunrise.js )

  end
end
```

Anybody has any experience with this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same trouble... It seems that the gem it's not designed to work inside an engine :-( I just made a dirty work around.

In my case, the issue was on generating a layout. It was the same error but with differente generator:

rails g bootswatch:layout simplex

I just have used sublimetext to open the file inside the gem:

```
subl /home/alfricomoros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-4.2.4/gems/twitter-bootswatch-rails-3.3.4.0/lib/generators/bootswatch/layout/layout_generator.rb
```

And temporarily I did the following change inside the method:

```
  def generate_layout
    app = ::Rails.application
    # ext = app.config.generators.options[:rails][:template_engine] || :erb
    ext = :erb
    template "layout.html.#{ext}", "app/views/layouts/#{theme_name}.html.#{ext}", {theme_name: theme_name, app_name: application_name}
  end
```

I'm not using a template library like haml.. just erb.

Then just Ctrl+S  on sublime text to save changes and retry the command. I get the command works properly:

```
~$ rails g bootswatch:layout simplex
      create  app/views/layouts/simplex.html.erb
~$
```

Then, undo the change in file and save again to not mess up the gem. Close your sublime.